# xDebug using Laravel 5.2 PHP7 phpStorm 10 on Homestead not launching

Tags: laravel-5, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

Using the latest and greatest Laravel 5.2 Homestead VM and trying to get xDebug setup with my latest and greatest phpStorm 10.  I pasted my php -i results here http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and followed the instructions provided to download, install and configure the correct version of xDebug.  I am using Chrome and the xDebug extension set to Debug and using IDE = phpStorm.

I am supposed to be able to simply launch phpStorm
https://drupalize.me/videos/zero-configuration-debugging-phpstorm?p=2017
and set a breakpoint and simply start listening for a debug connection.

I've read through several of these StackOverflow posts about similar configurations and spent a few hours so far trying to self-diagnose with no luck.  The phpStorm debugger simply isn't being fired from Chrome.

A pointer to installation instructions that work would be ideal, or I am happy to post all of my xDebug/php.ini settings to diagnose the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here after some more investigation turned up the following fix:

I needed to create a file...

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

with the following properties...

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.scream=0 
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

Comment: I found it helpful to add `xdebug.remote_autostart=1`. To see the effects, you may need to restart PHP: `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

Answer (score 0):

Scripted out so it can be handled during provisioning, and not manually after every destroy/up.

```
#!/bin/sh
# I heard you like xdebug

echo "*********************************************************"
echo "********** XDEBUG FOR Homestead/PHP7 SETUP **************"

echo "** Inserting xdebug.ini configuration settings **" 
cat << XDEBUG | sudo tee /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini
; configuration for php xdebug module
; priority=20
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey="phpstorm"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level=300
xdebug.scream=0
xdebug.cli_color=1
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
XDEBUG

echo "** Restarting php7.0-fpm **" 
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```